# directory permissions adding user in a group

Tags: user-management

I added a user using useradd

```
useradd -g upperdevs myuser
```

But when I do an id check I didn't see the upperdevs group.

```
id myuser
#uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser),27(sudo)
```

Probably this was the issue why I can't write to certain_dir, by doing `ls -l`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root upperdevs 4096 Sep  8 13:35 certain_dir
```

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably still logged in.

When you change a user's groups, that user needs to log out and back in for the change to take effect.